# Why use function in class if we can get result with simple print method?

Tags: python

I am learning python classes and using online source to learn python. But i am little but confused. Output of following class are same.

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def myfunc(self):
    print("Hello my name is " + self.name)

p1 = Person("John", 36)
p1.myfunc()
```

and

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("John", 36)
print("Hello My name is " + p1.name)
```

If output of both classes are same then why to use 2 functions for output.

Comment: This is probably for didactic reasons. The idea here is to introduce the concept of methods (functions which belong to a class and usually act on instances of the class).

Comment: Watch the differences: `self.name`  and `p1.name`. This is how to access a class attribute *inside* and *outside* a class.

Answer (score 1):

Asume that you now have 1000 persons. Okay?

If you use the second method (Just one function in Person class).

You will need a lot of lines to print all that:

```
p1 = Person("John", 36)
print("Hello My name is " + p2.name)
p2 = Person("Peter", 35)
print("Hello My name is " + p2.name)
p2 = Person("Don", 35)
print("Hello My name is " + p3.name)
... and so on
```

What if they ask to change the line to add the years to the printing line.
Well, that's a lot of work.
That's why you better use a function to it. To code reuse.

If you have a method that prints that, just change that and it's over.

```
def myfunc(self):
    print("Hello my name is " + self.name + " and i have " + self.years + "years"
```

)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are learning the language, yon don't have a lot of stuff to actually do something with the data you processed. Like many other beginners, you use print to "display something in the console log". But in real life, yon don't want to send data to the console. You may want to display it in a label or a button of a UI, maybe you will need to send this data to someone by email or by a network socket, or you may need to display it on a web page. That's why the class method `Person.myFunc` is prefered, so you can encapsulate the process in the class.

And in real world, `Person.myFunc()` will probably not call `print()` but instead, will return a result so you can do something useful with it.

Answer (score 0):

As you show yourself - one of them is a function which is attached to the `Person` class. Functions defined like this are called `methods`.

In your example it might be a personal preference what to use.

Usually when calling methods, they act on instances/variables of the class. The example might be a "Mickey Mouse" examples to show how to make methods

Answer (score 0):

The course is teaching you how classes work. A class is very similar to a function, except it groups a bunch of functions together. Try putting a function inside a function to help illustrate it to yourself.

```
def func_1():
    print('first function is running')
    def func_2():
        print('2nd function is running)
```

I'm not 100% on what the best practice is for nesting functions in functions.. that was only for an example.

Anyways, think of `func_1` as your class and `func_2` as your method. There's subtle differences with how python processes a class that makes it a little different, but essentially their logic is the same.

You should look more into what Objects are in python, and how they make up the language. The silly zen response is something like, "everything is an object, but only a few specific things are actually objects." It sounds really counter intuitive, but if you can grasp that then a whole lot more will start making sense.